# Checkout process not proceeding after 4 step in magento 1.9 for my theme

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.9.1

When I added a product to cart everything is working properly and when I continue for checkout process in that while registering the customer billing details I am unable to proceed from step 4 to 5. Please suggest me what is the exact issue I am new for Magento programming and I had readed lot of articles on it but didn't get success below is the screen shot given.
  Also i fing this post but it is not answere yet [post for magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532073/magento-checkout-continue-button-not-proceeding-to-next-step)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long investment of time and effort at last i got the solution here.
  **/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtm** i have changed this line

```
   <fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
     </fieldset>
```

to

```
    <fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
     </fieldset>
```